# ActiveModel::Model error when initializing class with no params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When running a test, if I try to create a new object using `User.new` I get an error. If instead I use `User.new({})`, it works fine.

**Isn't params supposed to be defaulted to empty if not passed in?**

`$ rails -v`

`Rails 5.0.0.1`

*user.rb*

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :country
end
```

*user_test.rb*

```
require 'test_helper'
class User < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should create an empty user when initialized with no params" do
    user = User.new
    assert_not_nil(user, 'user cannot be empty')
  end
end
```

*test result*

```
Error:
User#test_should_create_an_empty_user_when_initialized_with_no_parameters:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
    test/models/user_test.rb:7:in `new'
    test/models/user_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:User>'
```

Comment: What happens when you do User.new in a rails console? Do you have an initialize method in user.rb?

Comment: Are you sure the `User` in your `test` is the user *model* and not the user *test*?

Comment: From time to time, you just need someone to point out the obvious, thanks @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `attr_accessor` is used on a model for columns that are not actual columns in the SQL table.

So if your model has columns `:name`, `:email` and `:country`, then declaring `attr_accessor` is unnecessary. I think rails is waiting for you to declare them now.

Try commenting out the `attr_accessor :name, :email, :country` line, then re-run your test.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried uncommenting it, but didn't work. 

Anyway, `attr_accessor` is just the Ruby way to give getters and setters to the class. It doesn't seem to be a problem according to the [ActiveModel::Model doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html)

Answer (score 0):

**This may help**

Instead of including model class extend it like:

```
class Crime < ApplicationRecord
 //do your stuff here
end
```

Then you can use @user = User.new

Comment: This was just a mistake of naming the test exactly like the model. 

Changed the test name from `User` to `UserTest`, and it's all fixed.
Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

The `User` you're referencing in the test is the test itself.

The easiest solution is to follow Ruby convention and name the test class `UserTest`.

Comment: From time to time, you just need someone to point out the obvious, thanks.